# Linear algebra - Proof of a thesis concerning the height in triangles!

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors, triangles

My Math teacher gave us some tasks we should work on. I solved most of them already, however I still could not manage to figure out the solution for this one!
I would really appreciate, if someone of you could give me a hint or the name of this mathematic problem, so i can research in the Internet. Here is the task!

Proof that the following sentence is true for right-angeled triangles:

h²= |AC|²-|AC|²*(cos(a))²

[This is looks almost like the triangle from the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0BRb.jpg)

I should mention, that this task is taken from the field of linear algebra, so |AC| and h are vectors!

Thank you for your support!

Comment: It seems very unlikely that $\lvert AC\rvert$ and $h$ are vectors; more likely they are _magnitudes_ of some vectors not named here. Moreover, vectors have directions, none of which are indicated in the figure you linked to. It might be better if you edit this question to insert an exact copy of the task _as written_ (without your own interpretation), formatting the symbols and formulas as advised in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: 2 separate points labelled $'C'$ - both come up in the equation - very confusing. A bit of Pythagoras and some basic Trig. - try a bit harder.

Answer (score 0):

we get $$AC^2=(1-\cos(a)^2)=AC^2\sin(a)^2$$ and this is true since $$\sin(a)=\frac{h}{AC}$$